# Listing all ports as JComboBox

Tags: java, swing, arduino

I have a application in which I must list the available ports for connection with Arduino. I' m using RxTx. I have a problem in the  current code:
In my GUI i receive all ports as ArrayList from this row

```
public ArrayList<String> getPortIdentifiers() {
         Enumeration portEnum = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifiers();
         ArrayList<String> ports = new ArrayList<String>();

         while (portEnum.hasMoreElements()) {
            CommPortIdentifier currPortId = (CommPortIdentifier) portEnum.nextElement();
                ports.add(currPortId.getName());
         }
            return ports;
    }
```

In my controller i get this result and set result to the view

```
this.view.setListPorts(listPorts);
```

In my view i get thus ArrayList and set array to ComboBox

```
new JComboBox(this.listPorts.toArray());
public void setListPorts(ArrayList<String> ports) {
                this.listPorts = ports;
            }
```

But i'm receiving error on this row number

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: if `new JComboBox(this.listPorts.toArray());` is the entire line, then that isn't being saved to a variable

Comment: Well, one thing I can see happening is that `ArrayList` isn't thread safe, so maybe the code for adding to the list executes in such a way that it makes it think it has another element, and then the code thread you're showing us tries to access that element, which is still actually null in memory, because the `add` method didn't finish all the way.

Comment: Which line does the error occur? We'll need more context then that do diganose the error

Answer (score 1):

Here's some more code:

```
public class CommunicationController implements ActionListener {
 public CommunicationController() throws IOException, TooManyListenersException {
       // initialize connection here
        this.communication = new TestComunication();
        ArrayList<String> listPorts = this.communication.getPortIdentifiers();
      this.view.setListPorts(listPorts);
 }
}
```

...

```
public class CommunicationView extends JPanel {
   private JComboBox portsList;
   private ArrayList<String> listPorts;

    public CommunicationView() {
   ....
   ..... 
 this.portsList = new JComboBox(this.listPorts.toArray());
}
 public void setListPorts(ArrayList<String> ports) {
        this.listPorts = ports;
    }
}
```

.....

```
public class TestComunication {
    public ArrayList<String> getPortIdentifiers() {
         Enumeration portEnum = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifiers();
         ArrayList<String> ports = new ArrayList<String>();

         while (portEnum.hasMoreElements()) {
            CommPortIdentifier currPortId = (CommPortIdentifier) portEnum.nextElement();
                ports.add(currPortId.getName());
         }
            return ports;
    }
}
```

And the error [image]